# Cannot find module './user'. in app.component.ts

Tags: angular6

Getting the error as  Cannot find module './user' in CLI, attached the screenshot below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV2x3.png)

As I am new to angular, please suggest how to resolve the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your file path is wrong don't get confused. or restart server

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your folder structure, but the import { User } statement is looking for a file called user.ts in the same folder as app.component.ts (ie in src/app). Two things could be wrong:

- The file is called something else (eg user.model.ts)
- The file is in another directory

Also make sure you export User (export class User {...) in that file - but that isn't the error here as missing an export has a different error message.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the reply. Can you once brief the point you mentioned, "You don't show your folder structure, but the import { User } statement is looking for a file called user.ts in the same folder as app.component.ts (ie in src/app) ".   The path of the user.ts is "F:\Angular\AngularForms\src\app\template-form\user.ts" and the path of appcomponent.ts is "‪F:\Angular\AngularForms\src\app\app.component.ts"

Comment: show the folder structure of your angular projectmainly the app folder

Comment: F:\Angular\AngularForms\src\app, this is the folder structure of the app, khan Farman

Comment: Hi Sai, with that folder structure your import statement should read: import { User } from './template-form/user'.